# How can I create a new instance of ImmutableDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, immutability

I would like to write something like this:

```
var d = new ImmutableDictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } };
```

(using `ImmutableDictionary` from [System.Collections.Immutable](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/)). It seems like a straightforward usage as I am declaring all the values upfront -- no mutation there. But this gives me error:

> The type '`System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>`' has no constructors defined

How I am supposed to create a new immutable dictionary with static content?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can't create immutable collection with a collection initializer because the compiler translates them into a sequence of calls to the `Add` method. For example if you look at the IL code for `var d = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } };` you'll get

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32>::.ctor()
IL_0005: dup
IL_0006: ldstr "a"
IL_000b: ldc.i4.1
IL_000c: callvirt instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32>::Add(!0, !1)
IL_0011: dup
IL_0012: ldstr "b"
IL_0017: ldc.i4.2
IL_0018: callvirt instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32>::Add(!0, !1)
```

Obviously this violates the concept of immutable collections.

Both your own answer and Jon Skeet's are ways to deal with this.

```
// lukasLansky's solution
var d = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();

// Jon Skeet's solution
var builder = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<string, int>();
builder.Add("a", 1);
builder.Add("b", 2);   
var result = builder.ToImmutable();
```

Comment: Note that I've now changed my code, as the previous code wouldn't have compiled :(

Comment: Oh, that's revealing answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

Either create a "normal" dictionary first and call `ToImmutableDictionary` (as per your own answer), or use `ImmutableDictionary<,>.Builder`:

```
var builder = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<string, int>();
builder.Add("a", 1);
builder.Add("b", 2);
var result = builder.ToImmutable();
```

It's a shame that the builder doesn't have a public constructor as far as I can tell, as it prevents you from using the collection initializer syntax, unless I've missed something... the fact that the `Add` method returns `void` means you can't even chain calls to it, making it more annoying - as far as I can see, you basically can't use a builder to create an immutable dictionary in a single expression, which is very frustrating :(

Comment: Yeah, a little irritating, but at the same time that is something that the developer can encapsulate themselves in a helper class or something.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I'd be interested in the reasoning behind the lack of constructors for builders. For the immutable collections themselves, that's fine - but not for the builder...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: In fact, my previous post wouldn't have worked due to the return type of `Add` being void. Ick! See the horrible edit...

Comment: Collection initialiser for the builder ;-) of course, I jest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to play with builders now. :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet The builder has an `AddRange` method for key value pairs, which is pretty close to the constructor for it, but I think by this point it'd be easier to use the extension methods that were also published with the library.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: It's not nearly as useful as either making the call fluent *or* providing a parameterless constructor to use collection initializers though. The `Builder` type seems *nearly* useless at the moment, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I agree generally, but I think with the extension methods the problem is fairly limited.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: It raises the question about why the builder types exist when their usefulness is so limited. And they *could* be so much more useful, very easily - either with fluent Add methods *or* public constructors.

Comment: The "normal" dictionary + `ToImmutableDictionary` approach seems like one to avoid, because there's considerable overhead in building a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` - it creates a hashtable internally to enable efficient lookup. But as far as I can tell, `ToImmutableDictionary` just iterates over the content, so all that work to build the hashtable is effectively wasted.

Comment: @IanGriffiths: Yes, it depends on whether this is is in a piece of code which is performance sensitive. For one-time setup, for example (static readonly fields) it's probably the simplest approach - especially as it allows for the collection initializer. I like your helper idea... it's just a shame it's needed :(

Comment: Absurd that the Add method isn't fluent.  Who wrote that builder class?  It should be `ImmutableDictionary.Builder.Add("aKey","aValue").Add("anotherKey","anotherValue").Build()` like every other builder ever written.

Comment: @KevinWong, I actually think supporting a dictionary initializer (making the Builder ctor public) would be even better than fluent `Add` methods here as the final syntax is vastly simplified.

Answer (score 24):

So far I like this most:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

Comment: Be aware that this will cause unnecessary extra work at runtime - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28448092/497397 for why

Answer (score 16):

You could use a helper like this:

```
public struct MyDictionaryBuilder<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable
{
    private ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Builder _builder;

    public MyDictionaryBuilder(int dummy)
    {
        _builder = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => _builder.Add(key, value);

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        set { _builder[key] = value; }
    }

    public ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToImmutable() => _builder.ToImmutable();

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Only implementing IEnumerable because collection initializer
        // syntax is unavailable if you don't.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

(I'm using the new C# 6 expression-bodied members, so if you want this to compile on older versions, you'd need to expand those into full members.)

With that type in place, you can use collection initializer syntax like so:

```
var d = new MyDictionaryBuilder<int, string>(0)
{
    { 1, "One" },
    { 2, "Two" },
    { 3, "Three" }
}.ToImmutable();
```

or if you're using C# 6 you could use object initializer syntax, with its new support for indexers (which is why I included a write-only indexer in my type):

```
var d2 = new MyDictionaryBuilder<int, string>(0)
{
    [1] = "One",
    [2] = "Two",
    [3] = "Three"
}.ToImmutable();
```

This combines the benefits of both proposed advantages:

- Avoids building a full `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
- Lets you use initializers

The problem with building a full `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is that there is a bunch of overhead involved in constructing that; it's an unnecessarily expensive way of passing what's basically a list of key/value pairs, because it will carefully set up a hash table structure to enable efficient lookups that you'll never actually use. (The object you'll be performing lookups on is the immutable dictionary you eventually end up with, not the mutable dictionary you're using during initialization.)

`ToImmutableDictionary` is just going to iterate through the contents of the dictionary (a process rendered *less* efficient by the way `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` works internally - it takes more work to do this than it would with a simple list), gaining absolutely no benefit from the work that went into building up the dictionary, and then has to do the same work it would have done if you'd used the builder directly.

Jon's code avoids this, using only the builder, which should be more efficient. But his approach doesn't let you use initializers.

I share Jon's frustration that the immutable collections don't provide a way to do this out of the box.

**Edited 2017/08/10**: I've had to change the zero-argument constructor to one that takes an argument that it ignores, and to pass a dummy value everywhere you use this. @gareth-latty pointed out in a comment that a `struct` can't have a zero-args constructor. When I originally wrote this example that wasn't true: for a while, previews of C# 6 allowed you to supply such a constructor. This feature was removed before C# 6 shipped (after I wrote the original answer, obviously), presumably because it was confusing - there were scenarios in which the constructor wouldn't run. In this particular case it was safe to use it, but unfortunately the language feature no longer exists. Gareth's suggestion was to change it into a class, but then any code using this would have to allocate an object, causing unnecessary GC pressure - the whole reason I used a `struct` was to make it possible to use this syntax with no additional runtime overhead.

I tried modifying this to perform deferred initialization of `_builder` but it turns out that the JIT code generator isn't smart enough to optimize these away, so even in release builds it checks `_builder` for each item you add. (And it inlines that check and the corresponding call to `CreateBuilder` which turns out to produce quite a lot of code with lots of conditional branching). It really is best to have a one-time initialization, and this has to occur in the constructor if you want to be able to use this initializer syntax. So the only way to use this syntax with no additional costs is to have a struct that initializes `_builder` in its constructor, meaning that we now need this ugly dummy argument.

Comment: Note that you can't define a public parameterless constructor on a `struct`, so you'd have to make this a `class`.

Comment: Ah. You were allowed parameterless constructs on a `struct` in the preview of C# 6 that was available when I originally wrote that. Using a `class` adds an extra allocation, meaning that this is more than just syntactic sugar - it would then impose a runtime overhead. That's why I made it a `struct`. So I've made a slightly clunky update that enables this to continue to work efficiently, but with the slightly unfortunate need to add a useless ctor arg. (The JIT compiler optimizes the argument out of existence in release builds, retaining the runtime efficiency of the original.)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that implementing `IEnumerable` is not needed assuming one uses the index-based initialization only. Before looking at this answer, I actually didn't know the index-based initialization was based on the presence of an indexer in the class... I thought it was only possible to use with `IDictionary`.

Comment: C# 12 (.NET 8.0) has primary constructors that can be parameterless, so the struct definition can be `public readonly struct MyDictionaryBuilder<TKey, TValue>() : IEnumerable where TKey : notnull { ... }`, make `_builder` readonly and initialized with a field initializer, and drop the constructor in the body.

Answer (score 14):

Or this

```
ImmutableDictionary<string, int>.Empty
   .Add("a", 1)
   .Add("b", 2);
```

There is also AddRange method available.

Comment: For the record, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.add?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Immutable_ImmutableDictionary_2_Add__0__1_), you're creating 2 immutable dictionary here, once every time you call Add.

Comment: Of course, it's immutable after all. For small loads it really doesn't matter as they are short lived as per larger there is always AddRange.

Answer (score 2):

The following method works quite well for me:

```
var dictionary = ImmutableDictionary.CreateRange(
    new []
    {
         KeyValuePair.Create("a", 1),
         KeyValuePair.Create("b", 2),
    });
```

Although it requires creating a KeyValuePair for each input it is a simple way to create a ImmutableDictionary and can be easilty abstracted away using an extension method if needed.

Comment: It also creates an extra intermediate array, something that the solution of [Ian Griffiths](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497397/ian-griffiths) does not do. But it has a natural beauty of not requiring any extra helper types defined by the user.

If you want to reduce verbosity of the repeated `KeyValuePair.Create` and don't mind being explicit about the key and value types, you can rephrase the statement as:
`var dictionary = ImmutableDictionary.CreateRange(new KeyValuePair<string, int>[] { new("a", 1), new("b", 2)});` (blame StackOverflow for lack of multiline code samples in comments).

Answer (score 1):

There is another answer I don't see here (maybe it's a new method?):

Just use the `CreateRange` method to create a new ImmutableDictionary using an `IEnumerable<KVP>`.

```cs
// The MyObject record example
record MyObject(string Name, string OtherStuff);


// The init logic for the ImmutableDictionary
var myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
var dictionary = ImmutableDictionary
   .CreateRange(myObjects.Select(obj => new KeyValuePair<string, MyObject>(obj.Name, obj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom `ImmutableDictionaryLiteral` class with an implicit operator to make a syntax very close to what you want.

```cs
public class ImmutableDictionaryLiteral<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public static implicit operator ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>(ImmutableDictionaryLiteral<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
        return source.ToImmutableDictionary();
    }
}
```

Then you call it by declaring a `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` variable and initializing with a `ImmutableDictionaryLiteral<TKey, TValue>` value.

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string> dict = new ImmutableDictionaryLiteral<string, string>()
{
    { "key", "value" },
    { "key2", "value2" }
};
```

This also works with object initializer syntax

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string> dict = new ImmutableDictionaryLiteral<string, string>()
{
    ["key"] = "value",
    ["key2"] = "value2"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this syntax:

```
var dict = ImmutableDictionaryEx.Create<int, string>(
                (1, "one"),
                (2, "two"),
                (3, "three"));
```

Can be easily achieved using this method:

```
public static class ImmutableDictionaryEx {

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="ImmutableDictionary"/> with the given key/value pairs.
    /// </summary>
    public static ImmutableDictionary<K, V> Create<K, V>(params (K key, V value)[] items) where K : notnull {
        var builder = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<K, V>();
        foreach (var (key, value) in items)
            builder.Add(key, value);
        return builder.ToImmutable();
    }

}
```