# How to initialize a ConcurrentDictionary? Error: "Cannot access private method 'Add' here"

Tags: c#, dictionary, private, concurrentdictionary, idictionary

I have a static class in which I am using dictionaries as lookup tables to map between .NET types and SQL types. Here is an example of such a dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> SqlServerMap = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    {typeof (Boolean), "bit"},
    {typeof (Byte[]), "varbinary(max)"},
    {typeof (Double), "float"},
    {typeof (Byte), "tinyint"},
    {typeof (Int16), "smallint"},
    {typeof (Int32), "int"},
    {typeof (Int64), "bigint"},
    {typeof (Decimal), "decimal"},
    {typeof (Single), "real"},
    {typeof (DateTime), "datetime2(7)"},
    {typeof (TimeSpan), "time"},
    {typeof (String), "nvarchar(MAX)"},
    {typeof (Guid), "uniqueidentifier"}
};
```

Then I have a public method below which passes in a .NET type and it returns the string value of the corresponding MS SQL Server type using this dictionary. However, since this is being used as a lookup table for making database queries, I think it makes sense to make it a `ConcurrentDictionary`. I changed it to:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> SqlServerMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>
{
    {typeof (Boolean), "bit"},
    {typeof (Byte[]), "varbinary(max)"},
    {typeof (Double), "float"},
    {typeof (Byte), "tinyint"},
    {typeof (Int16), "smallint"},
    {typeof (Int32), "int"},
    {typeof (Int64), "bigint"},
    {typeof (Decimal), "decimal"},
    {typeof (Single), "real"},
    {typeof (DateTime), "datetime2(7)"},
    {typeof (TimeSpan), "time"},
    {typeof (String), "nvarchar(MAX)"},
    {typeof (Guid), "uniqueidentifier"}
};
```

But now it underlines everything red within the `{}` (i.e. all key value pairs of the `ConcurrentDictionary`) and the error is:

> Cannot access private method 'Add' here

I don't think it's because I initialize it as `private static readonly`, because I just tested by making a `public static` version and I got the same error.

Comment: As your collection is not going to change, you could now use the [ImmutableDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx).
While this also has issues with the initialize, there are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033629/how-can-i-create-a-new-instance-of-immutabledictionary/28448092#28448092).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The collection initializer that you're using to populate the collection only works if the collection has an `Add` method of an appropriate signature and accessibility.  `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't have a public `Add` method, so you won't be able to use a collection initializer with it.

You can provide some initial data by passing an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` as a parameter to the constructor, or you can call `TryAdd` (or `AddOrUpdate`, or any of the other methods with `Add` in the name) in a loop after creating the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: Ah ok I see, thanks. I wish I could just have it already initialized in a `static ConcurrentDictionary` since I know it's not going to change and I just want to access it quickly. I'll see what I can do though.

Comment: @Drew And you can, by passing an `IEnumerable` to the constructor, rather than using  a collection initializer.

Comment: Ohh I misunderstood what you meant in your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 47):

Try this

```
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> SqlServerMap =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>(
        new Dictionary<Type, string>()
        {
            {typeof(Boolean ), "bit"             },
            {typeof(Byte[]  ), "varbinary(max)"  },
            {typeof(Double  ), "float"           },
            {typeof(Byte    ), "tinyint"         },
            {typeof(Int16   ), "smallint"        },
            {typeof(Int32   ), "int"             },
            {typeof(Int64   ), "bigint"          },
            {typeof(Decimal ), "decimal"         },
            {typeof(Single  ), "real"            },
            {typeof(DateTime), "datetime2(7)"    },
            {typeof(TimeSpan), "time"            },
            {typeof(String  ), "nvarchar(MAX)"   },
            {typeof(Guid    ), "uniqueidentifier"}
        }
    );
```

Updated: if you are using C#6(Roslyn 2.0 Compiler), you can use the new Dictionary Initializers.

```
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> SqlServerMap =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>
    {
        [typeof(Boolean )] = "bit"             ,
        [typeof(Byte[]  )] = "varbinary(max)"  ,
        [typeof(Double  )] = "float"           ,
        [typeof(Byte    )] = "tinyint"         ,
        [typeof(Int16   )] = "smallint"        ,
        [typeof(Int32   )] = "int"             ,
        [typeof(Int64   )] = "bigint"          ,
        [typeof(Decimal )] = "decimal"         ,
        [typeof(Single  )] = "real"            ,
        [typeof(DateTime)] = "datetime2(7)"    ,
        [typeof(TimeSpan)] = "time"            ,
        [typeof(String  )] = "nvarchar(MAX)"   ,
        [typeof(Guid    )] = "uniqueidentifier"
    };
```

Example
https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ZgjsR

Answer (score 5):

As a code example to Servy's accepted answer, in order to initialize a `ConcurrentDictionary` at instantiation, you can pass a type that impements `IEnumerable` (like a `List`) of `KeyValuePair` types to the constructor:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> SqlServerMap =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>(
        new List<KeyValuePair<Type, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Boolean), "bit"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Boolean), "bit"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Byte[]), "varbinary(max)"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Double), "float"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Byte), "tinyint"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Int16), "smallint"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Int32), "int"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Int64), "bigint"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Decimal), "decimal"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Single), "real"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(DateTime), "datetime2(7)"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(TimeSpan), "time"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(String), "nvarchar(MAX)"),
            new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(Guid), "uniqueidentifier")
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

As your collection is not going to change, you could now use the [ImmutableDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx).
While this also has issues with the initialize, there are solutions proposed for this [question about initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033629/how-can-i-create-a-new-instance-of-immutabledictionary/28448092):

A simple solution provided by @LukášLánský is

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

and a better performing version provided by @IanGriffiths is

```
public struct MyDictionaryBuilder<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable
{
    private ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Builder _builder;

    public MyDictionaryBuilder(int dummy)
    {
        _builder = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => _builder.Add(key, value);

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        set { _builder[key] = value; }
    }

    public ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToImmutable() => _builder.ToImmutable();

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Only implementing IEnumerable because collection initializer
        // syntax is unavailable if you don't.
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said @Servy in his answer, collection initialization works for types with `Add` method. But also it should work, if extension method with name `Add` and appropriate signature exists. So you could create one for concurrent dictionary. Initialization will be thread-safe, due to fact you are using static field initializer.