# How to initialise ReadOnlyDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-6.0

I have an unchanging dictionary that is exposed in a class.

Currently my code looks like

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class FooClass
{
    private static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> _validRevisions 
        = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte>(
            new Dictionary<string, byte>() { 
                { "1.0", 0x00 },
                { "1.1", 0x01 },
                { "1.2", 0x02 },
                { "1.3", 0x03 }
            } );

    public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> ValidRevisions => _validRevisions;

    // other FooClass contents...
}
```

I've used the backing field `_validRevisions` as I could not figure out a better way of creating a shared constant dictionary property. Is there neater way to manage this or maybe I should just make the field public?

My main question being is there a shorter way to initialise the `_validRevisions` field itself? Creating a Dictionary inline to pass it into a Dictionary (that happens to be read only)  seems a bit... of a code smell. Is it? Is there a better way?

EDIT: one more thing about the ROD I just noticed, there are no methods to support checking if it contains a given value... is there a reason for that related to it' read-only-ness?

Comment: You tagged C#4 but used a C#6 feature (the => operator), which one are you using?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Whoops, wasn't aware that was C#6! Will change now

Comment: Dictionary<K, V> implements IReadOnlyDictionary<K, V> so your _validRevisions can be an instance of Dictionary, whereas ValidRevisions can just expose IReadOnlyDictionary part.

Comment: @Ivan that would allow the user to cast and modify it. Not mentioned as a constraint in the question though.

Comment: Yep, the idea of this is that the exposed dictionary would be unmodifiable

Comment: Note that you can use an automatically implemented property instead: `public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> ValidRevisions { get; } = new ...`

Comment: _"there are no methods in a `ReadOnlyDictionary` to support searching it by value"_ but a dictionary also dont has this method

Comment: @TimSchmelter normal dictionaries have the `ContainsValue()` method -- not quite the same I'll clarify in question

Comment: @Toby: but how is this question related to the original question(how to initialise ...)? Don't ask btw-questions, ask a separate question

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, my train of thought got away from me! :D

Comment: If performance is a concern, see this answer for ImmutableDictionary; which has the same scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28448092/361842

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you don't mind having an `IReadOnlyDictionary` instead of a `ReadOnlyDictionary`, you could use this, since `Dictionary` implements `IReadOnlyDictionary`:

```
private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> _validRevisions
    = new Dictionary<string, byte>
       {
           { "1.0", 0x00 },
           { "1.1", 0x01 },
           { "1.2", 0x02 },
           { "1.3", 0x03 }
        };

public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> ValidRevisions => _validRevisions;
```

Comment: That would allow the user of this class to cast `ValidRevisions` back to a `Dictionary<string, byte>` and modify its contents. That is not mentioned as a constraint in the question though.

Comment: @CodeCaster just made a console to try it out, you are right. Didn't think it would be possible

Comment: @CodeCaster, as mentioned in the comments above, I would indeed like this to be immutable (is that not the same thing as what you're saying?)

Comment: @Toby yes, my example makes it mutable, so it will not suit your case

Comment: @CodeCaster user of this class can use reflection to change private readonly field of `ReadonlyDictionary` which holds decorated dictionary instance. I always wonder why casting interface to some data type is considered to be legal behavior of client

Comment: @Sergey heh, that's true.

Answer (score 33):

Update: In .NET 7 we got the `AsReadOnly` extension method for `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> readonlyDict = dict.AsReadOnly();
```

---

Original answer:

The [`ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is just a wrapper around a normal dictionary and there is only one [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712981(v=vs.110).aspx) to initialize it which takes another `Dictionary` instance.

So **no**, there is no shorter way. But i'd use the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) to initialize complex static objects:

```
private static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> _validRevisions;

static FooClass()
{
    IDictionary<string, byte> dict = new Dictionary<string, byte>() { 
            { "1.0", 0x00 },
            { "1.1", 0x01 },
            { "1.2", 0x02 },
            { "1.3", 0x03 }
        };
    _validRevisions = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte>(dict);
}
```

Comment: Am I completely crazy or was there some extension method like "AsReadOnly"  that converted the Dictionary to its readonly counterpart?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You are not insane, but `AsReadOnly` is an extension for collections, not for dictionaries, so it will work with lists or arrays.

Comment: `public static ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T2> AsReadOnly<T, T2>(this Dictionary<T, T2> source) => new ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T2>(source);` ← There you have it 

Comment: This equally depends on what `T2` actually is, the runtime will comply with what you tell it, even if that's a little contradictory.

For example, `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<byte>>` will still expose a mutable list as the `Value` for each `Key`.

In practice, if you're building up such a dictionary internally and just wanting to expose it as readonly, then you'll have to re-implement each `Value` as its own `IEnumerable`

Comment: In .NET 7 there is now an `AsReadOnly` extension method on `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest version I made

```
private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, byte> _validRevisions => 
new Dictionary<string, byte>() { { "1.0", 0x00 }, { "1.1", 0x01 }, 
{ "1.2", 0x02 }, { "1.3", 0x03 } }
```

Comment: The question asks about initializing a `ReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>`, not an `IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>`. The former is a concrete type and the later is an interface.