# Immutable dictionary property initialization in C#

Tags: c#, initialization, immutable-collections

I've lost several days trying to debug an issue that boils down to this:

Properties of type `IImmutableDictionary` can appear to be initialized in code but actually remain empty.

1. Why is the compiler allowing this? (I'm using .NET 6.0.417 on Linux)
2. Should I stay away from this type of dictionary initialization?

Example class

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> DictProp { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public IImmutableDictionary<string, string> ImmutDictProp { get; set; } = 
        ImmutableSortedDictionary<string, string>.Empty;
}
```

Illustration code

```
var bad = new TestClass
{
    // This works fine
    DictProp =
    {
        {"uno", "one"},
        {"due", "two"}
    },
    
    // This does NOT initialize the field, and compiler is happy
    ImmutDictProp =
    {
        { "uno", "one" },
        { "due", "two" }
    }
};
Trace.Assert(bad.DictProp.Count == 2);
Trace.Assert(bad.ImmutDictProp.Count == 0); // <<<< expecting 2 elements


var good = new TestClass
{
    ImmutDictProp = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "uno", "one" },
        { "due", "two" }
    }.ToImmutableSortedDictionary()
};
Trace.Assert(good.ImmutDictProp.Count == 2);
```

Contrary to some comments, this question is more than mere Immutable Dictionary instantiation. I'm asking about the initialization of a property and the absence of a compiler error. I'll provide an answer summarizing what I've learned.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.add?view=net-8.0#returns (see the "Returns" section)

Comment: The collection initializer calls the `Add` method. The new instances are returned but discarded.

Comment: The collection initializer syntax "does NOT initialize". The collection is created and then `Add` is called. The [`Add` method of `ImmutableSortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesorteddictionary-2.add?view=net-6.0) returns a new `ImmutableSortedDictionary` instance. The compiler can't catch this because there is no compilation error. Yes, never use collection initializer syntax for an immutable collection. Yes, an indication of the issue would be helpful. It's probably possible to catch in a code analyzer.

Comment: Jonathan Dodds made a very good TL:DR of the [very good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033629/how-can-i-create-a-new-instance-of-immutabledictionary) that answers all these questions and how to circumvent it.

Comment: It looks like the question will remain "duplicate". Some notes FWIW...
The constructor used by the initialization block is 'internal' which seems like a bug.
In my case, I migrated a property from `IDictionary` to `IImmutableDictionary` and there were **no compiler errors indicating the code broke**. It seems like a combination of things contributed to my problem. I think immutable collections should NOT allow initialization in this manner as it's clearly an error.